# How to edit WebAssembly Text Format (`.wast`/`.wat`) files using NeoVim?

Tags: neovim, filetype-assembly, filetype-lisp

The latest version of VIM includes some basic support for `.wat` files (although it doesn't highlight the `global` directives directly), but the latest version of NeoVim doesn't. In NeoVim, I can set the `filetype` to `lisp`, and some things work correctly then (because WebAssembly is a LISP-like language), but many things do not. Is there a better way?

It's important for me because I am developing [a compiler for my programming language](https://aecforwebassembly.sourceforge.io) that outputs `.wat` files and assembles them using `wat2wasm` from the WebAssembly Binary Toolkit.

Comment: In general, NeoVim tries to port over runtime files from Vim. Perhaps that hasn’t happened yet for the wat filetype, or perhaps it uses vim9script in which case the porting is more challenging.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like VIM never actually supported *.wat but actually was using *.wast support for *.wat. This was [rectified only recently](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/3ea62381c527395ae701715335776f427d22eb7b), which is why *.wat may still appear to have support.

If you want support, you'll either need to use *.wast extension or override the ftdetect back to the old way:

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.wat setfiletype wast
```

Comment: What is the difference between `.wast` and `.wat`?

Comment: Take a look here: https://webassembly.js.org/docs/contrib-wat-vs-wast.html